# Generating signatures for AWS S3 in Google Scripts

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, authentication, amazon-s3, google-apps-script

I'm trying to generate the signature in Google Scripts without much luck.

My code is as follows:

```
function getAwsData(){
  var AWS_SECRET = '[AWS_SECRET]';
  var expiresDt = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60 * 24);
  var path = '/MYFOLDER/ACTIVATION.csv'
  var stringToSign = 'GET\n\n\n' + expiresDt + '\n' + path;
  var hmac = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_1, AWS_SECRET,stringToSign, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  var signature = encodeURIComponent(Utilities.base64Encode(hmac));
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/MYFOLDER/ACTIVATION.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS_ACCESS_ID]&Expires="+expiresDt+"&Signature="+signature);
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(response, ",");
  console.log(csvData);
  }
```

Can someone please see where I've gone wrong? I've followed the document here: http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I'm signing the hmac incorrectly.

```
  var hmac = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_1, stringToSign, AWS_SECRET,Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
```

Comment: You are also not properly url-escaping the signature.  Any `+` appearing in the signature must be rewritten as `%2B`.  Additionally, though potentially less critically due to the way S3 interprets the request, `/` becomes `%2F` and `=` becomes `%3D`.